Are extensions of uniformly continuous open maps also open?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and let $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ be their completion.
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a uniformly continuous map. Then $f$ admits a unique continuous extension $\hat f: \hat X \to \hat Y$.
Question. If $f$ is open, is $\hat f$ also open?
My guess is that this is not true (otherwise it would likely be a theorem in the literature), but I am having trouble finding a counter-example. I tried to draw on the construction used in this answer to a different question, but didn't succeed.

Hint: Think about inclusion maps of subsets of the real line with the standard metric.

Thanks a lot. Very simple example indeed !

You should write an answer to your own question to clear it from the "unanswered" queue.

Following the hint proposed by Moishe Kohan, let $f$ be the inclusion map from $]0,1[$ into $\Bbb{R}$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous and open. Now, the completion of $]0,1[$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$. However, the unique continuous extension of $f$ to $[0,1]$, which is the inclusion map from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb{R}$, is not open, since $[0,1]$ is not open in $\Bbb{R}$.
